# Boolean order of operation in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Why does the below code result in true if type = 7 and seq = 224?

RPGLE free form:

```
if (type = 6 or                 
    type = 7 or                 
    type = 9) and               
    not (seq = 224 or seq=249);
```

I had to rewrite it to:

```
if (type = 6 or                 
    type = 7 or                 
    type = 9) and               
    seq <> 224 and 
    seq <> 249;
```

but why? I am guessing it has something to do with the NOT operator.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that either `type` or `seq` wasn't what you thought it was, or the code you actually ran wasn't what you show here. Both snippets are logically equivalent, and should have produced identical behavior.

Comment: I was debugging it and checked both of them, however I am no longer able to recreated it. I believe it could have been due to me recompiling while in debug mode or something similar. All I am certain of is that after I changed it to the second statement it ran as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `NOT` has a higher precedence than `AND` or `OR`
[RPG IV Reference manual operator precedence](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/opprec.htm)

1. ()
2. Built-in functions, user-defined functions
3. unary +, unary -, NOT
4. **
5. *, /
6. binary +, binary -
7. =, <>, >, >=, <, <=
8. AND
9. OR

However, the expression you show should evaluate to false...

```
**free

 dcl-s flag ind;
 dcl-s seq int(5) inz(224);
 dcl-s type int(5) inz(7);

   flag = (type = 6 or
           type = 7 or
           type = 9) and
            not (seq = 224 or seq=249);

   dsply ('Flag=' + flag);
   *INLR = *ON;
   return;
```

Joblog shows:

> DSPLY  Flag=0